# Parametrization for a set - Surface integral

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Hello i really need some help with this exercise. I dont know how to start and how i can find a parametrization for the given set.

The set F ist given by $ F := \lbrace (x,y,z) | (\sqrt{x^2 +y^2} - R)^2 +z^2 = r^2)$

Also $r,R$ are real and positive and $ R > r$

How can i find a parametrizition for $F$ ? Do i need some special coordinates ?

Comment: Why not simply use $x$ and $y$ as parameters?

Comment: Could you write down the surface integral that you need to compute? Sometimes the function/vector field that you need to integrate hints a possible parametrization.

Answer (score 1):

The surface defined by the set $F=\{(x,y,z)|\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-R\right)^2+z^2=r^2\}$, with $r<R$ can be described parametrically a number of ways.

We can choose, for example, $x$ and $y$ as parameters and write

$$z(x,y)=\pm\sqrt{ r^2-\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-R\right)^2}$$

for $(R-r)^2\le x^2+y^2\le (R+r)^2$.  Then, the parameterized surface is described by

$$\vec r =\hat xx+\hat yy+\hat zz(x,y)$$

---

We could also use cylindrical coordinates, $(\rho,\phi,z)$, and use $\rho$ and $\phi$ as parameters to write

$$z(\rho)=\pm\sqrt{r^2-(\rho-R)^2} $$

for $R-r\le \rho\le R+r$, and $0\le \phi<2\pi$.  Then, the parameterized surface is described by

$$\vec r(\rho,\phi,z)=\hat \rho(\phi)\rho+\hat zz(\rho)$$